# Intellij Idea 12 GWT Application deploy to war

Tags: gwt, deployment, intellij-idea, war

How can I deploy my GWT Application to war file using Intellij Idea 12? I couldn't find any apt plugins or options for my IDE.

Comment: Create a WAR artifact.  That's all.  No plugins needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Configuring Artifacts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) help section.

Comment: Right now, that link produces a 404... (There's the problem with answering a question with web references - support documentation and blog posts get often removed after a couple of years.)